# Connect to docker-compose network using docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let say I have running orchestration with `docker-compose` with `docker-compose.yml` looking like this:

```
version: '2.2'

services:

  service1:
    # ...
    networks:
      - compose_network

  service2:
    # ...
    networks:
      - compose_network

networks:
  compose_network:
```

I aim to run and connect temporarily one container to `compose_network_1`. I tried using

```
$ docker run --net=compose_network <image for the job>
```

but I could not connect. I am also aware that docker-compose names the networks as `[projectname]_default`, so I also tried that variant, but with same result.

Is there a way I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 26):

I'm not sure if the `--net` option ever existed but it's now `--network`.

From `docker run --help`:

```
      --network string   Connect a container to a network (default "default")
```

As @maxm notes you can find the network name, with the DIR prefix of the compose project directory, then simply run it as you were trying:

```
$ docker run --network=DIR_compose_network <image for the job>
```

I wanted to connect on run as my container is transient (running tests) so I can't use a second `docker network` command in time before it quits.

e.g.  for my docker composition in a "dev" folder with no network name specified so uses the docker-compose "default" name, therefore I get the name `dev_default`.

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
2c660d9ed0ba        bridge              bridge              local
b81db348e773        dev_default         bridge              local
ecb0eb6e93a5        host                host                local

docker run -it --network dev_default myimage
```

This connects the new docker container to the existing docker-compose network.

Answer (score 7):

The network name is going to be something like `name-of-directory_compose_network`. Find the name with `docker network ls`

I had success with:

```sh
docker-compose up # within directory ./demo
docker run -itd -p "8000:8000" --hostname=hello "crccheck/hello-world"
# outputs: 1e502f65070c9e2da7615c5175d5fc00c49ebdcb18962ea83a0b24ee0440da2b
docker network connect --alias hello demo_compose_network 1e502f65070c
```

I could then `curl hello:8000` from inside my docker compose containers. Should be the exact same functionality as your commands, just with an added alias.

Answer (score -1):

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  service1:
    networks:
      - virtual-network

  service2:
    networks:
      - virtual-network

  service3:
    networks:
      - virtual-network
networks:
  virtual-network:
```

use this command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).